# How to insert a QR code and some text in a pdf template in Python (preferably) to generate tickets

Tags: python, django, qr-code

Hi I am currently making a web application for a congress at my university. The project is not too complicated, but the main functionality is that a user should register himself for the congress and get sent a pass/ticket in PDF through email, with a QR code identifying him/her. This is so that the user can then assist to any event in the congress where a volunteer will read said QR code at the entrance so we can keep track of assistance and reward it at an individual level, as well as keep track of room capacity for COVID reasons.

The website is being built using Django and DjangoRest, hence I want to keep using Python wherever I can. I have looked at tools such as [ReportLabs python package](https://www.reportlab.com/dev/docs/). It is quite dense and I can't find what I am looking for, which is:

- Open a pdf template
- Fill the template with the information regarding the user: name and email for example.
- Paste/Insert the QR code generated for the user (this is already done).

It seems pretty simple but I just can't find how to do it, so any input would be very much appreciated.

Maybe I am getting at this all wrong idk, is there a better way to generate tickets??

Comment: Hii, thanks for commenting. What do you mean with assistant??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SimpleDocTemplate` in reportlab and create a list of story. For example:

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Spacer

def get_ticket_file(ticket_obj):
    buffer = BytesIO() # We dont want to store pdf
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(
        buffer, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=50, leftMargin=50, topMargin=50, bottomMargin=50
    )
    story = []
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    qr_image = Image(ticket_obj.get_qr_image(), # this is your method that returns qr image of your ticket.
                 )
    story.append(qr_image)
    story.append(Paragraph("`SomeTitle`", styles["Heading2"]))
    story.append(Spacer(1, 2)) # some space between lines
    # And so on.... add more paragraph with styles like `styles["Normal"]`
    doc.build(story)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer
```

In your view, return this pdf file

```
from django.http import FileResponse

# other logics 
pdf_file = get_ticket_file(ticket_obj)
return FileResponse(pdf_file, as_attachment=True, filename="ticket.pdf")
```

Also, you can use [xhtml2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/xhtml2pdf/) library that has simple document and you can create pdf files with HTML file. it's easier and you write less code. For example:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from io import BytesIO
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def get_ticket_file(ticket_obj):
    html = render_to_string("ticket.html", # This is your html file. Read xhtml2pdf document in order to style it.
                            {"ticket_obj": ticket_obj})
    buffer = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(src=html, dest=buffer, encoding="utf-8")
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer
```

Comment: Dude this is awesome, thank you so much for the answer, will definitely use this. Sorry I cant upvote you since I just created my account